# Yii Datepicker Cloned with jQuery Not Working

Tags: jquery, yii, datepicker

**BACKGROUND:**

I'm using the PHP [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and the Javascript library jQuery. I have a form created with Yii, which includes a datapicker input element. I'm using jQuery to clone the `datepicker` input.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem I'm running into is that the new cloned `datepicker` doesn't work.

**HTML/PHP:**

```
   <div class="clone">
       <?php 
           $this->widget(
               'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
               array(
                   'model'=>$model,
                   'attribute'=>'Date',
                   'value'=>$model->date,
                   'options'=>array(
                   'changeMonth'=>true,
                   'changeYear'=>true,
                   'showButtonPanel'=>true,
                   'autoSize'=>true,
                   'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                   'defaultDate'=>$model->date,
               ),
               'htmlOptions'=>array(
                   'class'=>'date'
               ),
           ));
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.clone').clone().append().insertAfter('.clone')
```

I really appreciate any help or guidance thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need a closing `?>` PHP bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker cannot be cloned with bound events because if you do so they will point to the original datepicker element. Instead clone the datepicker without any events, remove the class hasDatepicker from the cloned element and initialize the datepicker.

```
// Cloning the original element
$clonedElement = $('.clone').clone().insertAfter('.clone');
// For some reason class hasDatepicker must be removed before init, otherwise it wont work
$clonedElement.find('input[name="Model[Date]"]').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b65p24a6/

Comment: thank you so much ... please bear with me  newbie here ..... i followed ur code but still the second datepicker point to the first one i did i initialized it again like this    $('.clone input[name="Model[Date]"]').datepicker();  still the same

Comment: If you are using an older version of jQuery < 1.5.0 its required to add false parameter to the clone method to omit the bound events,

Example: .clone(false)

Comment: If this doesn't work you could try to remove all events from the cloned element and its children by using jQuery .off() or .unbind() methods depending on your jQuery version.

Comment: thanks alot .... I added                                                                                          .attr("id", "")
    .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
    .removeData('datepicker')
    .unbind()
    .datepicker(); and now its working

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `date` class to your datepicker and select it with `clone` class. I think the problem is it. Try to replace `$('.clone').clone().append().insertAfter('.clone')` with `$('.date').clone().append().insertAfter('.date')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize your datepicker for new element
`$('.clone').datepicker()` with your options